# About Blackberry PDF Viewer API libarary

Tags: blackberry

Is there any libarary for writing PDF Viewer? i have tried JPedal as well as Codeplex  pdf libararies for blackberry but they are not working?Is any one knows library for blackberry PDF Viewer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any existing open source library but you can always try porting something from android for instance.